# Derivative error with respect to bias in binary cross entropy

Tags: neural-networks, bias, backpropagation, derivative, cross-entropy

I will do research using NN with 1 hidden layer. To calculate loss using binary cross entropy and for the activation function using sigmoid. I found the derivative formula from Sadowski, 2016 (link:   [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pjsadows/notes.pdf](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epjsadows/notes.pdf))  as follows:

[image]

A weight Wji connecting hidden layer unit j to output unit i has gradient:

[image]

[image]

The paper does not explain how the derivative of error with respect to bias. So, how is the formula for the derivative of error with respect to bias? Is there any other source that can explain it because I have to include the source. Thank you so much.

Comment: Does [the answer by gunes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/600130/374567) answer your question? If so, consider accepting it to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For bias, you can take the input as $1$ in these equations, i.e. $x_k=1$. So, that will be

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial b^1_j}=\sum_i (y_i-t_i)w_{ji}(h_j(1-h_j))$$

where $b^1_j$ is the bias term of neuron $j$ in the hidden layer.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much. Is that mean if there is bias bi, I can take hj =1? So derivative E/ derivative bi = (yi-ti)1 ? is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct